# Angular 7, Warning in budget, maximum exceeded, didn't get what is wrong?

Tags: angular, webpack, bundle, angular7

I have a angular 7 app.

When I build project with --prod, I have a warning in budgets.

`angular.json`

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/tbc-capital-web",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/env.js",
          "src/web.config"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [],
        "es5BrowserSupport": true
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": true,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

Build output image:

[image]

The thing is I can't understand what is wrong here.

Non of the files are more then 2mb.

Question 1: Which generated file (or files) triggers this warning?

Question 2: How can I fix this without increasing warning size in `angular.json`

It will be great if you provide not just answers but little explanations to.

Answer (score 6):

To keep it simple, the budget could be defined as the target build size **not to overcome** when you build the application.

It can be used for hosting, for instance, on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) : when you host on such services, you have a free service that is limited, so you would like not to overcome it so that you don't have to pay.

The budget is **the total size of all your files combined**, not the size of your largest file.

You can ignore this most of the time, this is really a deployement issue : it's just that the CLI includes this budget by default.

To remove it, you can go into your `angular.json` package and find this :

```
          "budgets": [{
            "type": "initial",
            "maximumWarning": "2mb",
            "maximumError": "5mb"
          }]
```

Simply change the values and it won't pop a warning again !

Answer (score 1):

### What does **budgets** mean?

> A performance budget is a group of limits to certain values that
>   affect site performance, that may not be exceeded in the design and
>   development of any web project.

In our case budget is the limit for bundle sizes.

See also:

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3216
- https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-size-budgets